# Haskell `$` in F# possible?

Tags: haskell, f#, operator-overloading, binary-operators

In Haskell, we can write

`print $ abs $ 3 - 5`

using `$` .

In F#, we can write

`printfn "%d" << abs <| 3 - 5`

However, in many cases in F#, it would be also useful to have the same functionality of `$` since the above are simply expressions with binary operators.

The trick of Haskell `$` is that has somewhat the lowest precedence among its binary operators.

So, I investigated again

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/#operator-precedence

and I observe, unfortunately, that there are no operators in lower precedences that can overload safely because all of them seem essential.

Do you have any ideas on this?

Do you think Haskell `$` in F# is possible??

Comment: Not sure what your ultimate goal is here, so I ask: You do know about [interpolated strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/interpolated-strings)?

Comment: Hi, it's not about the ultimate goal thing, as I mentioned it's simply about expressions with binary operators. Sure I know the stuff, but not sure why you mentioned it.

Comment: FYI it's not idiomatic F# to use `<<` or `<|` (I work primarily in F# and I don't use them at all). You can always express things going "forwards" with `>>` and `|>`. It's a very intentional stylistic difference. This example would become `3 - 5 |> abs |> printfn "%d"`. Something to bear in mind if you plan to write F# for others to read. In this particular example I would simply add parens `printfn "%d" (abs (3 - 5))`. Perfectly non-clever! 

Comment: I mentioned it (interpolated strings) because I wasn't sure if this was an XY problem. Interpolated strings in F# is relatively new, so there's much documentation that doesn't mention it.

Comment: HI @TheQuickBrownFox Come to think of it, that totally makes sense. Thanks for sharing the idiomatic view.

Comment: @BentTranberg Probably the reason you mention interpolated string is that the symbol of `$` is used there. The Haskel binary operator symbol `$` has no relation to it.

Comment: No, that's not why. I explained why I mentioned it in my previous comment.

Comment: @BentTranberg OK, now I see I let you misunderstand due to my sample code using `printfn`. Which is actually purely on purpose for printing the result of the implementation of the binary operator that is the target of this QA.

Comment: I misunderstood nothing. Again I refer to my explanation as to why I mentioned it.

Comment: Then I would say "misleading by my Question" because this is not XY problem and Interpolated strings in F# is nothing to do with the expression of binary operators.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like Haskell, F♯ also allows you to define *new* infix operators, not just overload existing ones. Unlike Haskell however, you can't select precedence (aka fixity) at will, nor select any non-letter Unicode symbol. Instead, you must choose from `!`, `$`, `%`, `&`, `*`, `+`, `-`, `.`, `/`, `<`, `=`, `>`, `?`, `@`, `^`, `|`. The fixity is then determined by analogy with the standard operators, in a way I don't entirely understand but what does seem to hold is that for any single-symbol infix, you can make a custom one with the same fixity by adding a `.` in front.

So, to get a lowest-fixity operator you'd have to call it `.|`. However, `|` is left-associative, so you couldn't write `printfn "%d" .| abs .| 3 - 5`. However I'd note that in Haskell, your example would also rather be written `print . abs $ 3 - 5`, and that can indeed be expressed in F♯:

```ml
let (.|) f x = f x
printfn "%d" << abs .| 3 - 5
```

To transliterate `print $ abs $ 3 - 5`, you'd need a *right*-associative operator. The lowest-precedence custom right-associative operator I can manage to define is `.^`, which indeed gets the example working:

```ml
let (.^) f x = f x
printfn "%d" .^ abs .^ 3 - 5
```

However, this operator doesn't have very low precedence, in particular it actually has higher precedence than the composition operators!

---

Really, you shouldn't be doing any of this and instead just use `printfn "%d" << abs <| 3 - 5` as you originally suggested. It's standard, and it also corresponds to the preferred style in Haskell.

Comment: On right- vs left-associativity: I and many others consider the right-associativity of `$` to be a mistake in the first place, so it's not obvious that `.|` being left associative is actually a bad thing. Generally `f $ g $ h $ x` can be written `f . g . h $ x`, so changing the associativity wouldn't really lose anything, and you would gain the ability to write things like `f (g x) (h y)` as `f $ g x $ h y` whereas currently there's no good, parenthesis-free way to express that.

Comment: @DanielWagner yeah-ish. As I said, `f . g . h $ x` is normally preferred (or `f . g $ h x`), but there are also things that can't be written this way, such as `max <*> sqrt $ negate $ pi - 3`, which would require extra parentheses: `(max <*> sqrt) . negate $ pi - 3`. The reason that this seldom arises in practice is that it only happens with infix expression that have a function type, which usually means either `.` or the function applicative / function monad (which I also consider dubious style). Anyway you can't really make the point that changing the associativity wouldn't lose _anything_.

Comment: `ap max sqrt . negate $ pi - 3`... But yes, I take your point. I would say that what you lose is much more rare than what you gain. I don't remember ever seeing something like what you describe.

Comment: Thanks for your versatile answer and for taking your time! I've tried a lot of things reading your answer and I reached the exact consequences. The official document is not complete I feel because of lots of unknown behavior, especially I don't understand why only `.^` or `^^` will be accepted for the custom right associative. I really appreciated again.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks. It's a very interesting discussion, however still it seems identical to write `printfn "%d" << abs <| 3 - 5`